# Invariant complex structures for simple Lie groups

Tags: complex-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For which simple Lie groups there exists a left-invariant complex structure?

Comment: Clearly for the complex ones, so the question is probably whether these are the only ones? (could naturally be asked for semisimple groups too)

Comment: [This MathSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1945438/35400) can be relevant.